# Check programatically the status of an action in oozie workflow from another oozie workflow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am running some code in oozie workflow named WF1's action named AC1.. This workflow is not scheduled but runs continuously.. usually action AC1 will get its turn 4 times a day. Time at which this action runs is not known previously.
Now, there is another Oozie workflow WF2, scheduled to run at 4:00 AM in the morning using Oozie coordinator. This WF2 runs for 3-4 minutes only as this is a small code required to be run in off-peak hours. 
In this WF2, we want to check the status of workflow action AC1 (running as part of WF1 [everytime AC1 instance runs, a new id gets assigned to it]. Is it possible to get the status of AC1 using name only, without knowing the id?

I know I have a workaround where I can store the status of AC1 in Hive table and keep querying the same to know the status. But if something is offered out of the box, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it (as you mention).

The built-in way is to use the [job information](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Job_Information) 
So you can do a simple get and get a response with job status on all actions, in the below example you can go to `actions` look for your action name and change the `status` for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
.
{ 
  id: "0-200905191240-oozie-W",
  appName: "indexer-workflow",
  appPath: "hdfs://user/bansalm/indexer.wf",
  externalId: "0-200905191230-oozie-pepe",
  user: "bansalm",
  status: "RUNNING",
  conf: "<configuration> ... </configuration>",
  createdTime: "Thu, 01 Jan 2009 00:00:00 GMT",
  startTime: "Fri, 02 Jan 2009 00:00:00 GMT",
  endTime: null,
  run: 0,
  actions: [
    {
      id: "0-200905191240-oozie-W@indexer",
      name: "AC1",
      type: "map-reduce",
      conf: "<configuration> ...</configuration>",
      startTime: "Thu, 01 Jan 2009 00:00:00 GMT",
      endTime: "Fri, 02 Jan 2009 00:00:00 GMT",
      status: "OK",
      externalId: "job-123-200903101010",
      externalStatus: "SUCCEEDED",
      trackerUri: "foo:8021",
      consoleUrl: "http://foo:50040/jobdetailshistory.jsp?jobId=...",
      transition: "reporter",
      data: null,
      errorCode: null,
      errorMessage: null,
      retries: 0
    },
```